# Magento 2 Admin Pointing to Wrong Locale

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-community, locale

I have a Magento CE 2.0.7 install on Apache with PHP7 and MySQL 5.7. There are no plugins or modified/custom code. I set the locale to en_CA on installation through the web setup wizard.

I changed to production mode and the frontend directs to the proper pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_CA/ directory but the backend/admin section points to pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/ causing a 404 as that does not exist. The proper en_CA directory is in the file system with the proper permissions set but the admin side is requesting the en_US directory.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have a resolution?

Comment: well did you create a backend theme en_CA? it sounds like it defaults to the en_US as it is expected

Comment: I did not create a backend theme. There have been no modifications. When changing to production mode the static content is deployed under en_CA but when going to the admin in a browser the request is sent to en_US. Shouldn't the backend point to en_CA the same as the frontend?

Comment: no, it shouldn't be, unless you create a backend theme

Comment: Okay. So to fix this, static content must be deployed with the locale option for en_US. For anyone else that runs into this issue the command to run would be "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments on the original post, the backend will only request from en_CA(or a locale other than en_US) if there is a backend theme.

To have the CSS/JS working correctly on the backend the static content of the en_US locale must be deployed. The following command will do this.

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: en_US is implied and can be removed